# Matlab compilation returning an error when run

Tags: bash, matlab

After putting in numerous hours, I felt ready to run my code on my friend's high end computer. I compiled my application (named Zeta). However, when I entered:

```
sh '/home/nicbit/Desktop/run_Zeta.sh' /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_RuntimeD
```

to test this on my computer, I received the following error code:

```
------------------------------------------
Setting up environment variables
---
LD_LIBRARY_PATH is .:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/runtime/glnxa64:  
/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB
/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime
/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/usr/local/MATLAB
/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/MATLAB
/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/client:/usr/local/MATLAB
/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64
/home/nicbit/Desktop/run_Zeta.sh: 1: eval: /home/nicbit/Desktop/Zeta: Permission 
denied
```

In response I tried:

```
sudo sh '/home/nicbit/Desktop/run_Zeta.sh' /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_RuntimeD
```

which resulted in the same error. I also chmoded the file so that

```
ls -la '/home/nicbit/Desktop/run_Zeta.sh'
```

returns:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nicbit nicbit 1135 Jan 23 18:50 /home/nicbit/Desktop/run_Zeta.sh
```

but the same error code resulted. Does anyone know how to solve this issue.
Thank you

Comment: Sounds like run_Zeta.sh contains a bug; probably missing some all important `""` quotes. Any chance you can show the content of run_Zeta.sh?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I copied the code to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/L0tWN54Y

Comment: what I find odd is that this code was automatically generated by Matlab... so surely others must be having this issue

Comment: the script is absurdly badly written, though it should work in this case. It expects there to be a file named Zeta in the same directory, and that this file is executable, so what does `ls -l /home/nicbit/Desktop/Zeta` say?